# How to handle if there is no default program to launch .pdf file using Runtime.getRuntime().exec("filename ")?

Tags: java, default, runtime.exec

I have PDF file and I'm opening it using

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler "+filename+".pdf");
```

I'm able to open file properly, but if there are no default programs to open pdf file i need to handle that and show to user

I tried following code

```
public String openPdfFile(String filename){
    String returnValue="";
    try {
          if(checkIfFileExists(filename+".pdf")){
          Process pPDF= Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler "+filename+".pdf");
          returnValue=""+pPDF.waitFor();
        }
    }      

 } catch (Exception e) {
       return "ERROR";
  }
        return returnValue;
}
```

it will always return 0 even when there is no default program to launch. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you want to manually browse and open a PDF?

Comment: No sam,  I'm not opening any  fileExplorerDialog to manually locate the  file . i'm just passing the the complete file path and using Runtime.getRuntime().exec() method I'm opening it

Comment: you do understand that different operating systems have different ways to open files by extension?

Comment: Hi Oleg Mikheev, i do understand that but right now i'm only concentrating on Windows

Comment: If there is no default program, you can try to open the file in latest browsers (like firefox, chrome etc.,). So, when you get 0 as return value, you can conditionally choose browser to open a pbf. Following worked for me `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(c:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox d:\\pdflocation\\pdfname.pdf)`

Comment: Hi thank you for your suggestion for using a browser to open  but i have requirement to show an error message if there are no default application installed, is there any way we can achieve that ?

Comment: @AndrewThompson ,that was really good suggestion and i tested it and it worked but its an AWT api but i was looking for an only in pure JAVA api please let me know if u have any idea how to achieve this using only java api's

Comment: @AndrewThompson,sorry for the inconvenience as you mentioned  i don want to include any GUI classes in my project

Comment: @AndrewThompson i will try using process builder and will get back if i could meet my requiremnts .thank you

Comment: *"i don want to include any GUI classes"*  ***Why?***  Don't forget, we are not talking about GUI **components** here, just classes in the same package.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using [`Desktop.open(File)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#open-java.io.File-) instead.. It throws:

> `IOException` - if the specified file has no associated application or the associated application fails to be launched..

The OP replied (paraphrased)..

> That was really good suggestion and I tested it and it worked but it's an AWT API & I was looking for this functionality only in pure Java API..

AWT is a **package in the J2SE**. You cannot get more 'pure' than that. If, for some reason by 'pure' you mean 'with no GUI classes' then that doesn't make sense either, since if the user of the code is on a computer that can display a PDF, then that method should work.

Further, **use of `exec` is as impure Java as you can get** (besides that being a *very poor implementation*<sup>1</sup> of use of a `Process`)!

Here is a small table comparing the `exec` implementation shown above with the `Desktop` method.

```
**OS    **exec  **Desktop   
Windows maybe   true
OS X    false   true
Linux   false   true
Unix    false   true
```

#### Meaning of values

- `true` means it *should* work, barring a bug in the JRE or as mentioned, no suitable viewer for the file type.
- `false` it will fail reliably - every time.
- `maybe` it will work, presuming:

  - The output or error stream does not become full.
  - The file name has no spaces in the path or name.
  - There is a suitable viewer for that file type.

So I cannot see how using `exec` could be considered preferable to using a cross-platform method like `Desktop.open(File)`.

1. See [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) for many good tips on creating and handling a process correctly.  Then ignore it refers to `exec` and use a `ProcessBuilder` to create the process.